# Technical name of the slope on electric guitar body

Tags: electric-guitar, string-instruments

Most common electric guitars have a slope on the edge of the largest part of their body, where the forearm lays. Has this slope a specific name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s referred to as a contour, or forearm contour.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and: is it the same for acoustic guitars? I am searching for details on building techniques of the forearm contour in acoustic guitars.

Comment: Yes although they’re less common on acoustics. I would imagine it would be difficult to build a contour into an acoustic. An arch top has sort of a natural contour built in. Good luck!

Comment: I would like to see how's made _inside_ the left corner from which originates the contour in guitars as these: https://www.maestroguitars.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Waist.jpg https://www.washburn.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/WCG15SCE12.jpg

Comment: Found it, finally. https://s958.photobucket.com/user/edwinsonguitar/media/MOL--Paul%20R%20Crossover%20Consort/IMG_0009_4-3.jpg.html?sort=2&o=17

Comment: Interesting, they use a solid block of wood with the contour built into it. Great find!